# Showing Custom POI (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Can you help?

Background Info.

I have android google maps v2 running in activity2 no problems.
In Activity1 I want to plot POI's onto google maps in activity2, I have an xml created with my POI data.

Question:
I want my android app activity1 to run like this:

1) Select one option A-Z? ***"user selects: M"***

2) What colour inside field M? M-Blue, M-Red, M-Green? ***"user selects:M-Green"***

3) Now Select Range (M-Green 1 to M-Green 200) ***"user selects:M-Green 17 through to M-Green M21"***

And then it shows markers M17,M18,M19,M20,M21 on android google maps on the next activity.

***What would be the best way to implement this? Im not after your code before you ask just an ideal direction i.e. any resourses/webpages that will help me complete this actual task please?***

***Thank you for your time.
Adrian.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if what you want is something like this, but anyway here it is:

In the first activity I would have

1. one [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) which would load values from a to z represented
   by an arrayadapter of characters
2. one [radiogroup](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/) with three values, one for each color. If you want the user to choose among many colors you probably have to use a color picker.
3. Since the values are too many to choose from, I think that a [seekbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)
   would be the ideal choice. See an example [here](http://android-helper.blogspot.gr/2011/05/android-simple-seekbar-example.html)

Then I would pass the selected values to the second activity with the standard approach, via the extras of an intent after pressing e.g. a submit button.

On the second activity, on the onCreate handler, I would receive the selected values and check their validity. Then I would map them to their metadata which I guess are given (on a web server or localy in a sqlite database). And then I would construct the [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) that will appear on the map.

Simple enough, hope this helps!